# How to make the parameters of returning function required or not based on current function parameters Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am new to Typescript and trying to mimic styled-components at a much lower scale. In my case, I want to make children required if user passed `true` in createStyledComponent for children parameter, otherwise make the children optional.

I kinda  have a newbie solution to my problem where I am returning 2 different functionsm, one with required children and other with optional.

Is there a better and concise way to do this task?

```js
const createStyledComponent = (
    type: any,
    component_style: CSSProperties | undefined,
    children?: boolean
) => {
    if (children) {
        const returnComponent = ({
            children,
            style,
        }: {
            children: any;
            style?: CSSProperties | undefined;
        }) => {
            return React.createElement(
                type,
                { style: { ...component_style, ...style } },
                children
            );
        };
        return returnComponent;
    } else {
        const returnComponent = ({
            children,
            style,
        }: {
            children?: any;
            style?: CSSProperties | undefined;
        }) => {
            return React.createElement(
                type,
                { style: { ...component_style, ...style } },
                children
            );
        };
        return returnComponent;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try and take a stab at generics honestly. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Something like the following might work for your use case.

```
type StyledProps<C extends boolean> = {
    style?: CSSProperties;
    children: C extends true ? ReactNode : ReactNode | undefined;
};

const createStyledComponent = <C extends boolean>(
    type: any,
    component_style?: CSSProperties,
    childrenRequired: C = false as C
) => {
    const returnComponent = ({ children, style }: StyledProps<C>) => {
        return React.createElement(
            type,
            { style: { ...component_style, ...style } },
            children
        );
    };
    return returnComponent;
};
```

But your implementation details might vary. I definitely would stray away from big if, else render blocks that are largely the same. In that type of scenario it can be helpful to abstract these blocks into separate components, or do inline conditionals

```
return (
    <div>
        {/* other shared render logic */}
        {value === true && (
            <div>value true render</div>
        )}
        {value === false && (
            <div>value false render</div>
        )}
    </div>
)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You want [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

---

You have two signatures here:

One where `children` are required:

```
function createStyledComponent(
  type: any,
  component_style: CSSProperties | undefined,
  children: true, // explicit true
): (
  props: { children: React.ReactNode, style?: CSSProperties }
) => React.ReactNode
```

And one where they are not:

```
function createStyledComponent(
  type: any,
  component_style: CSSProperties | undefined,
  children?: false // missing or explicit false
): (
  props: { children?: React.ReactNode, style?: CSSProperties }
) => React.ReactNode
```

Then you can write the implementation as follows:

```
function createStyledComponent(
    type: any,
    component_style: CSSProperties | undefined,
    // children parameter here is not actually required,
    // since the implementation is identical
): (
  props: { children?: React.ReactNode, style?: CSSProperties }
) => React.ReactNode {
    const returnComponent = ({
        children,
        style,
    }: {
        children?: React.ReactNode;
        style?: CSSProperties | undefined;
    }) => {
        return React.createElement(
            type,
            { style: { ...component_style, ...style } },
            children
        );
    };
    return returnComponent;
};
```

Note that the `children` parameter to your function is gone in the implementation. It has no use at runtime since the logic is identical, but it does allows us to give the type system a tip and enforce what is required.

Now to test that out:

```
createStyledComponent('div', undefined)({}) // fine
createStyledComponent('div', undefined)({ children: <></> }) // fine

createStyledComponent('div', undefined, true)({ children: <></> }) // fine
createStyledComponent('div', undefined, true)({}) // error as expected, no children
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCAyoQApQRhKzBIDOcAvnAGbkhwDkUqGHAUH2YBXAHYZgEEXDTcUMJIRgBPADZIAJvgjhJSETAAUfOHGWUAXHBQilmY9O2QRemAH1aytZaKlylanRwAD5woupIzMDO6nYmaAAWwCrq3CKWMFBCSHYAlJZGJmB+tJZ4CUkpepbI6DAAdDUYAHIQ4dgeqkgA-N7EZBRUMDT0DHw5cAC8AHyIPPWNMC3hAsJiQ5LSsvKKnZqOuvoFpkoWVjaxDjrO+u6eSL2+AwH0IWERURoX5cmpPSwoKloSDG+XsRQoJVw0kSPz0fwWDTmS2ycA6aj+Pn6-iGgVG42ms1qiNqyJWonEGxkqG2dz2VxcRxMZnuZ1s9ji+2ubjRLMxfkGw2CoRE4Ui0QuJgA9JLoRVUnAwCgoCgQEh5FA4PEqEg4MB6CIIPBakIASolHBuABHITAbgxdlwaWoqJoHUwLW68BqVX6OQSKR63XhfTANAAkFwI7gsCQsowyoieFzYnNVoonkYvr856MMaTGYIhbI3AOtCSDwWtVCKAiLT0-STSM4B0mOLx1IS1smHmdhilFut74JpNEotpgDcA+7d0zj2xgteIve0UnXYY+Jmza7Xe4MGrUgRVLkSAAot6GVPt8zO9vW3geaU4HVn2X69y7thn3UeYxGDfb7KsIiJeOSrq2DBgSYu77pWe41nWTguJOEECEeNK7AhByGBw6jAAAbhw2BvGKGg5AYODro6MokXwaEKLSmFcgYOH4YRwqih86hkXGcpVHAAA8Uz8ZKMyUU6NG0Vs9EYZyDIsQRRFLiRMSmJkSDcYBCaWIJwmieM4kfJJ1LSWodKIYc8lscRnHYBkWTcWJMpUOQUDYAammpEAA)